# Unknown field type in query

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to query for "distinct" values in a table.
The idea is to run a query like this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fieldName FROM tableName WHERE ...
```

My attempt:

```
// distinct value struct
type DValue struct {
    Value interface{} `gorm:"column:value"`
}
...

var items []DValue
result := db.
    Table(tableName).
    Distinct(fmt.Sprintf("%s AS value", dbColumnName)).
    Order(fmt.Sprintf("%s asc", dbColumnName)).
    Find(&items)
   
var values []interface{}
for _, item := range items {
    values = append(values, item.Value)
}
return values, nil
```

The query runs like it should and everything seems to be working fine. I am getting an error like this in the logs: `[error] unsupported data type: 0x140004b2890` every time.

The issue seems to be the fact that my `Value` is of type `interface{}` but I cannot really set it to anything else since I do not know what type the field is.

Is there a way to get around that and keep the ambiguous type?